# Keep text unaffected by css filter effect

Tags: css, image, css-filters

When I apply a filter to darken the background of an image to make the text readable, it applies to *everything* within the div.

```css
.blog-container{
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    width: 280px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1688297969967-302de9c8bd5b?q=80&w=1887&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
}

.blog-container:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
    filter: brightness(55%) saturation(140%); /* only way I've managed to darken the background */

}

.blog-title, .blog-desc{
    width: 260px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 18px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.blog-title{
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    bottom: 45px;
}

.blog-container:hover .blog-title {
    -webkit-animation: slide-up 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0s forwards;
}

.blog-container:hover .blog-desc{
    -webkit-animation: slide-up 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0.1s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-up {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(80%); opacity: 1 }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); opacity: 1  }
}
```

I'm expecting that when I hover over the div, the background-image darkens and the text slides in and is **visible**

Comment: I should note, the css filter effects when applied, apply to the text, making it too lose its brightness and increase its saturation, so the darkening effect applied is rendered useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good effort! You're experiencing this issue because of how CSS inherently works: when you apply styling to a parent element, it naturally affects all the children inside it. This includes any filters or effects you add.

**Here's my suggested approach:**

To get around this, we should introduce a kind of 'intermediary' element. I've used `.blog-container::before` in this case, to dynamically generate an additional element. (You can read more about this approach in the [MDN doc's - CSS ::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)).

We need to ensure we apply our visual changes at the same hierarchical level as your other child elements, like the title and description.

This `::before` element is set to `position: absolute`, while its parent `.blog-container` is `position: relative;`. This allows us to position the `::before` element independently of the document flow. ([MDN Doc's - CSS Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position))

Then, we ensure this pseudo-element covers the entire parent (See Snippet). Don't forget to set `overflow: hidden` on the parent to prevent any spillover.

Now that we've done that we can target `::before` element's hover effect to tell it what to do when the element has hover; independently of other children. - **Magic!!**

Lastly, we sort out the stacking order. We do this by adjusting the `z-index` properties. We set the z-index of the `::before` element and the textual elements you want to appear on top. This ensures that the text is always visible and unaffected by the background effect.

```css
.blog-container {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    width: 280px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1688297969967-302de9c8bd5b?q=80&w=1887&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
    overflow: hidden; /* Added to contain the pseudo-element */
}

.blog-container::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    filter: brightness(55%) saturate(140%);
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.blog-container:hover::before { /* The magic line */
    opacity: 1;
}

.blog-container:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.blog-title, .blog-desc {
    width: 260px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 18px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2; /* Ensure text is above the overlay */
}

.blog-title {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    bottom: 45px;
}

.blog-container:hover .blog-title {
    -webkit-animation: slide-up 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0s forwards;
}

.blog-container:hover .blog-desc {
    -webkit-animation: slide-up 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0.1s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-up {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(80%); opacity: 1 }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-container">
  <h1 class="blog-title">
    Hello World!
  </h1>
  <span class="blog-desc">Lorum ipdum et sumit.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you man. I'm a python developer trying to break into the full stack world, I appreciate this. Informative and explanative. Not had the greatest interactions with the stack overflow community but you defied prior expectations! Preciate it a lot.

Comment: No worries, glad I could be of some help! 